# Why do I get HTTP Response Status Code 451 only when using the Java HTTP Client?

Tags: java, http, http-response-codes, java-http-client

I want to make a GET-request, which works fine with OkHttpClient, my webbrowsers and postman.
But when I use the Java HTTP Client, I receive the Response Code 451.
This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
             HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                   .uri(URI.create("*Some URL*"))
                   .build();

             
            HttpResponse<String> response=null;
            try {
                response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
                System.out.println(response.statusCode());
                System.out.println(response.body());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }System.out.println(response.body());
```

"451" is what is printed.
Why?

Comment: It appears you are not passing in any authorization header. It might be worth trying out to append an authorization header and then make the get request.

Comment: Get a network trace and compare what your client sends with what the other tools send.

Comment: Thanks for your help. @AsifKamranMalick almost right. Adding the Authorization-Header didn't help but the User-Agent-Header did it.

Comment: glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the "User-Agent"-Header solved my problem.

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                       .uri(URI.create("*URL*"))
                       .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
                       .build();
```